# Grails domain constraints mapping

Tags: mysql, grails, groovy, oracle11g

I'm working on grails 2.4.5
On the domain class, I define:

```
String CARD_NO
String USER_ID
String PASSWORD
```

and the constraints:

```
CARD_NO(nullable: false, blank: false, maxSize: 24, unique: 'USER_ID')
USER_ID(nullable: false, blank: false, maxSize: 32)
PASSWORD(nullable: false, blank: false, maxSize: 64)
```

However If I got script like:

```
"CARD_NO"                  VARCHAR2(24 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,
"USER_ID"                  VARCHAR2(32 BYTE),
"PASSWORD"                 VARCHAR2(64 BYTE),
CONSTRAINT "CARD_USER_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ISSUER_ID", "CARD_NO") ,
CONSTRAINT "USER_ID_UNIQUE" UNIQUE ("USER_ID") ,
```

Is this any possible way to mapping constraints with given script?
Any solution will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by **mapping** domain constraints with sql script? did you mean you want to create sql script that can represent grails domain constraint above?

Comment: No I mean that if I got the script and run it in db, means that we already have table, I'm looking for simple way to map domain class with that existing table. Because we need to define constraints in domain class to map with table in database. Hope that you got me. Thanks.

Comment: if the constraints are already defined in the DB you don't really have to reproduce them 1 to 1 in your domain class. I mean those constraints of course, that would be violated when hitting the DB, and not the ones that get validated on GORM site only, like `maxSize` or `blank`

Answer (score 0):

You only need to write what you need in domain class, for example, if you have 5 field in your actual table in database but you only need 3 field in your program, you can just write that 3 field in your domain class. That case also work with the relation, you can just write the relation that you need only.

But there is an exception if you want to filter or validate(all elemen) an domain class.

You can use grails [db reverse engineer plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/db-reverse-engineer) to get domain class from existing table.